# Getting gradle sync issue com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getFolder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**Unable to find method ''java.lang.String com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getFolder(com.android.utils.EnvironmentProvider)''
'java.lang.String com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getFolder(com.android.utils.EnvironmentProvider)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.**

Tried:

1. Deleting .gradle and sync back
2. reinstalled java and android studio

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The issue related to spoon library, gradle sync issue, which happens for everyone if we clear the `~/.gradle` cache:

1. If we downgrade `spoon` version to 1.5.0 then, we have to update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version from 3.6.4 to 4.1.2 then build is success and able to generate the aars.
2. If we use latest `spoon` version 1.5.1 then, we have to update `com.android.tools.build:gradle` version from to latest